# How do I speed up or parallelize this R code?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

This code works well but it is a little bit slow. I noticed that it only runs on only one core of the processor. It would probably be a bit faster if it used more than one core.

```
### proximity filter
options("scipen"=100)
library(geosphere)

# split up data into regions
splitdt<-split(geocities, geocities$airport_code)

## reduce cities
dat=geocities[FALSE,][]
currentregion=1

while (currentregion <= NROW(splitdt)){
    workingregion <- as.data.frame(splitdt[[currentregion]]) ## set region
    workingregion$remove = FALSE
    setDT(workingregion)
    #plot(workingregion$longitude,workingregion$latitude)
    currentorigin=1

    while (currentorigin <= NROW(workingregion)) {
        # choose which row to use
        # as the first part of the distance formula
        workingorigin <- workingregion[,c("longitude","latitude")] %>% slice(currentorigin) ## set LeadingRow city
        setDT(workingorigin)

        # calculate the distance from the specific row chosen
        # and only keep ones which are further than 20km
        workingregion<-workingregion %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(remove =
        ifelse(distHaversine(c(longitude, latitude), workingorigin) != 0 &  # keep workingorigin city
        distHaversine(c(longitude, latitude), workingorigin) < 17000,TRUE,workingregion$remove))

        # remove matched cities
        workingregion <- workingregion[workingregion$remove!=TRUE,]

        currentorigin = currentorigin+1
    }
    currentregion = currentregion+1
    # save results
    workingregion <- workingregion[workingregion$remove!=TRUE,]
    dat <- rbind(dat, workingregion) #, fill=TRUE
}
```

Comment: This question might be better asked on the [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Generally what you want to do is write a function that take a list as parameter so the list can be split and run on different cores. So you would need to replace your loops.  Then you can used your preferred package to run it in parallel. What you have above is pretty far away from where you need to be.

Comment: could the list `splitdt` be split up before the loops? then run each loop for each region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I noticed is the line:  ***`dat <- rbind(dat, workingregion)`***

This line of code is dynamically growing a vector in the loop which is not advised and will be slow.

I know that doesn't answer your question on parallelizing this loop. However, I just went through a similar exercise for collecting results from 100,000 SQL queries and sped up my code 60 times by being memory conscious.

I also paralleled my code with **foreach** and **%dopar%**. This is ideal for windows and it is easy to set up a cluster (instances of R on each core).

Below is an example that will help:

```
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
library(snow)

# Uses all but one core
cl = makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)

# Necessary to give your instances of R on each core the necessary tools to do what 
# happens in loop 
clusterExport(cl, '<variable names>')
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(packages ))

# parallel loop for going through each region (in your case)
foreach(currentregion = splitdt) %dopar% # iterates over splitdt to cores
{
<body of loop>
}

# Shut down cluster
stopCluster(cl)
stopImplicitCluster()
```

Here are some resources on speeding up R code:
http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Performance.html (by the man himself)
https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/performance.html

Hope this helps and good luck!